# Использование числа в качестве булева значения в тернарном операторе

Tags: javascript

Код решения задачи на нахождение факториала, который, думаю, многим знаком:

```
function f(n) {
    return n ? n * f(n - 1) : 1;
};
alert(f(5)); // 120
```

Что происходит во второй строчке на каждом шаге рекурсии? Отладчик не помог понять, ведь при:

```
n = 3;
if (n == true) {
    alert(111);
}
else {
    alert(222);
}
```

`n` всегда равно `false`. В общем, не понимаю условие.

Comment: Если JavaScript позволяет сравнивать `3` с `true`, то это ещё не значит, что всё должно быть очевидно в этом случае. Можно написать но-нормальному: `if (n != 0)` (или `if (n > 0)` - смотря что на самом деле нужно), и никаких проблем и неочевидностей не будет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> n = 3;
> if(n == true)
> ```

Это сравнение на самом деле приводит true к числу, т. е. к 1.
Очевидно, что условие `3 === 1` ложно.

А в условии

```
if (n)
```

выполняется приведение n к bool'у.
Учитывая, что n имеет числовой тип, это эквивалентно `n !== 0`, что тебе и требуется.

Answer (score 4):

Весь вопрос, опять таки, сводится к вопросу о приведении типов (не думаю, что тернарный оператор может ввести в заблуждение). В JS значения `true` или `false` жестко зафиксированно в [спецификации к языку](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-toboolean) в разделе `7.1.2 ToBoolean(argument)`.

1. В JS в плане приведения к булевскому типу проще определить то, что будет давать в результате приведения значение `false`. По спецификации это: `undefined`, `null`, `false`, `+0`, `-0`, `NaN` и `''`. Всё, больше ничего. Совсем ничего.
2. Все остальное приводится к `true`.

#### Неочевидные сразу примеры:

1. `[]`, `{}`, `new Object()`, `function() {}` приводится к `true`, потому что все это `Object`
2. `new Number(0)`, `new Boolean(false)` приводится к `true`, так как это тоже `Object` (обертка над примитивами)
3. `'0'`, `'undefined'` приводится к `true`, так как строки не пусты

[Вот пример на jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7b57k8L3/1/)

#### Исключение

Некоторые встроенные объекты в браузере могут неожиданно иметь значение `false`. Например, в старых (уже очень старых) IE `document.all === false`

Answer (score 1):

Во второй строке у вас для всех `n` > 0 вычисляется формула `n * f(n - 1)`, а для `n` = 0 возвращается `1` и ни каких дальнейших вычислений.

Почитайте [https://learn.javascript.ru/ifelse#преобразование-к-логическому-типу](https://learn.javascript.ru/ifelse#%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%83)

Comment: `n * f(n - 1)` вычисляется для всех `n`, не равных нулю.

Comment: @Regent, попробуем посчитать факториал отрицательного числа? :)

Comment: Так ведь я не про адекватность расчета факториала для отрицательного числа говорю, а про то, что в коде автора `n * f(n - 1)` будет вызываться и для `n`, меньших нуля, да ещё и уйдёт в далёкое далёко. Но ещё раз, абстрагируясь от факториала и другого кода: "Во второй строке у вас для всех `n != 0` вычисляется формула `n * f(n - 1)`" :)

Comment: @Regent, если абстрагироваться, то да `!=`.